# Define duration and throughput Oracle | datazen publish

Tags: oracle

I have a table like the below:

```
select  * from GENERAL_STATISTICS.PPLP_LOAD_GENSTAT2
```

[image]

The script for the table is pretty simple:

```
CREATE TABLE GENERAL_STATISTICS.PPLP_LOAD_GENSTAT2
(
  PPLP_NAME        VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  SUCCESSFUL_ROWS  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  START_TIME       DATE,
  END_TIME         DATE
)
```

I want to do 2 more rows, one column called Duration and another one next it to called Throughput. This last one, throughput is measured as the result of the sucessfull rows / duration , if i am not mistaken.

Moreover, very needful would be to create one more "dummy" column named **ON_TIME** which will compare that the start_time and end_time be the same day, for example on the 1st of each month.

How could I achieve this? Sorry but I am pretty stuck now.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
alter table GENERAL_STATISTICS.PPLP_LOAD_GENSTAT2
  add ( duration number generated always as (end_time - start_time)
      , throughput number generated always as 
            (case when (end_time - start_time) = 0 then null /*??? */
                  else successful_rows / (end_time - start_time)
                  end
            )
      , on_time varchar2(1) generated always as 
            (case when trunc(start_time) = trunc(end_time) 
                  then 'Y'
                  else 'N'
                  end
            )
      );
```

### Notes

1. For `throughput` you need to consider the case when `end_time-start_time` = 0 (e.g. your first row of data) otherwise you will get a ZERO_DIVIDE error at run-time.  I have used a `case` expression and returned `null` here - you may prefer 9999.99 or -1 or 0 or something else.
2. The `duration` value here is in days (with decimal places).  If you want hours, minutes or seconds instead multiply by the relevant factor.

Comment: Ok Tony, I am checking it. Thank you for your time!